# Process finished with exit code 0

Tags: python

I have this:

```
import  math
class Point:
    def move(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
def reset(self):
    self.move(0, 0)
def calculate_distance(self, other_point):
    return math.sqrt(
(self.x - other_point.x)**2 +(self.y - other_point.y)**2)
# how to use it:
    point1 = Point()
    point2 = Point()
    point1.reset()
    point2.move(5,0)
    print(point2.calculate_distance(point1))
    assert (point2.calculate_distance(point1) ==   point1.calculate_distance(point2))
    point1.move(3,4)
    print(point1.calculate_distance(point2))
    print(point1.calculate_distance(point1))
```

So I expect that it prints like this:

```
5.0
4.472135955
0.0
```

But In pycharm in the console it only prints this:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Where you can see the output?

I also add a attachment for clearness.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: It looks to me that, given the indentation of the last 9 lines of code, none of the code is even executed. The program finishes without really executing any code. Fix the indentation and it should at least execute properly. As it is now, the last 9 lines of code belong to the `calculate_distance` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `reset` and `calculate_distance` functions aren't in the `Point` class because of lack of indentation.

Try this. Now the functions are methods for Point class and all is working properly:

```
import  math

class Point:

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def reset(self):
        self.move(0, 0)

    def calculate_distance(self, other_point):
        return math.sqrt((self.x - other_point.x)**2 +(self.y - other_point.y)**2)


# how to use it:
point1 = Point()
point2 = Point()
point1.reset()
point2.move(5,0)
print(point2.calculate_distance(point1))
assert (point2.calculate_distance(point1) ==   point1.calculate_distance(point2))
point1.move(3,4)
print(point1.calculate_distance(point2))
print(point1.calculate_distance(point1))
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a window called "python console". The output of your script should be there...

Comment: thank you. But the added image shows the console? What other console there is?

Comment: I don't have pyCharm here, but maybe the online help can help you: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/pycharm-tool-windows.html As you can see in the screenshots the bottom line contains an entry python console.